# Strange behaviour in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I have a very simple program.

```
count = 0
total = 0

def iseven(number):
    if number % 2 == 0:
        True
    else:
        False

while count < 10 :
    if iseven(count):
        total = total * 2
    else:
        total = total * 4

    print total
    count = count + 1

print "final total is ", total
```

But this just prints zero on every iteration, and the final total is then zero.
So looks like the total value is not being updated.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your `iseven` function is missing a return statement, so the return value is always `None` (which in an if statement is interpreted as not true). You need to add `return ` before `True` and `False`.

Comment: if you start with `total = 0` it doesn't really matter what you multiply it by in which branch - you will always get 0.

Answer (score 1):

```
count = 0
total = 1

def iseven(number):
    if number % 2 == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

while count < 10 :
    if iseven(count):
        total = total * 2
    else:
        total = total * 4

    print (total)
    count = count + 1

print ("final total is ", total)
```

You are multiplying 0, which always results in 0

Output:

```
2
8
16
64
128
512
1024
4096
8192
32768
final total is  32768
```

Comment: as mentioned by mkcms, `iseven` doesnt return any values. Please edit your answer.

Comment: I have modified it. I didn't look at the iseven method as it was multiplying 0, and thus always returning zero.

Answer (score 0):

Your is_even function is missing a **return** statement.

Also, total should be initialised to 1, instead of 0 (1 is the **idempotent** value for the multiplication, not 0).